# No funciona el UTF-8 EN JSP

Tags: html, html5, jsp, utf-8

He estado intentando que mi formulario guarde el carácter `ñ` sin embargo siempre que realizo el debug este carácter es reemplazado ... a que se debe?

He intentado de la siguiente forma :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="fecha.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Agregar Usuario</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><!--opcion 1-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/><!--opcion 2-->
```

Ninguna de las dos opciones me ha dado resultado siempre que entro al debug, donde hago el request de la vista salen otros caracteres reemplazando la `ñ`

## NOTA

Mi problema no es al visualizar en la pagina, es en el formulario cuando envió los datos a guardar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## EDICION

El servidor que estoy utilizando es glassfish, probé la configuración al server  que igual por defecto es UTF-8 y mi problema continua.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema  se soluciono removiendo esta etiqueta de la pagina `.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Al parecer esto generaba que me convirtiera los acentos y se guardaran mal en la BD.

Espero a alguien le sirva!... Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de en los `.jsp`, que servirá para renderizarlo correctamente en la vista. Sería necesario que la codificación del `tomcat` este en `UTF-8` también.

Dentro la carpeta `conf` del `tomcat` debería haber un archivo `server.xml` mira que las etiquetas `Connector` tenga el atributo `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`

Debería quedar mas o menos así:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Aparte, la codificación del editor que estés utilizando también debería estar codificado a UTF-8 para evitar caracteres raros en el mismo.

Comment: modifique la pregunta y probé tu solución,  lastimosamente mi problema continua...